# How to generate unique api key and secret key in java

Tags: java, api-key, secret-key

I want to generate unique API Key and Secret Key and map each of this pair to unique projects in database. So I need a function to generate unique pair of keys.

How to generate unique api key and secret key in Java / database ?

Comment: have you tried Guid (in java that would be: UUID)?

Comment: what do you think when saying "secret key" ? What do you want to do with that ? (who owns the key, who can code, decode, etc.) ?

Comment: If you see ad network apis like Chartboost, Vungle, AdMob, etc. Once you create an application in their portal, you will be provided API Key and Secret Key. I want to replicate that feature

Comment: then you might be looking at sth like RSA, public + private keys pairs are rather well known and described encryption and authentication mechanism :) dependa what are you exactly up to.

Comment: I want to associate unique pair of key ( api key and secret ) to every project in my database. Using that, every client can authenticate REST url using public/private key authentication...

Answer (score 1):

I didnt study functionalities of Charboost, it's not the initial question.

I only get that you would get some secret/public Key (this site use signature for example), then an asymetric pair of key. After, you do what your want.

For this rather general purpose, I propose to use RSA, well implemented in Java (other algorithms exist).

see this post: [Generate RSA key pair and encode private as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709441/generate-rsa-key-pair-and-encode-private-as-string)

public key =>

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(512);
    byte[] publicKey = keyGen.genKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded();
```

private key =>

```
byte[] privateKey = keyGen.generateKeyPair().getPrivate().getEncoded();
```

Comment: will this give me a unique key every time ?

Comment: is there any doc that says KeyPairGen.... gives unique key throughout the life time?

Comment: is it safe to use database generated sequence to create unique pair of keys ?

Comment: usually, keys generated are differents, but relies on implementation (uses time, information system, ...). The only way to have pseudo-true randomness, is to use specialized hardware. database generate sequence or other soft generated have the same risks.