# How do I generate RSA key pair in JAVA (in openssl format)

Tags: java

How can I generate RSA key pair in Java using the format supported by OpenSSL?

Is there a way to generate them straight away like how we do in php?

the output should be like :

```
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA3Qa9WiabsxGv2uJBNNFn
   Ai3vEDF7Evr85RlgrviUSzkSupEH29PaazKX04/4M7mEQswVZOHSzkFRXiviImi1
   c1UrWlZENctS3A6P3RSqOonzrw6CVDJ4Nn/iydWlHhFaHBPpCopS537iHvJIey7K
   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

   -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
   MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQDdBr1aJpuzEa/a
   4kE00WcCLe8QMXsS+vzlGWCu+JRLORK6kQfb09prMpfTj/gzuYRCzBVk4dLOQVFe
   K+IiaLVzVStaVkQ1y1LcDo/dFKo6ifOvDoJUMng2f+LJ1aUeEVocE+kKilLnfuIe
   8kh7LsplosEQSxpfhjQcxt6qgRQk+eI9kyxczLvt2S0goAoO7rPIhi1LQFI1uUij
   U18a+vsu9uv/mMAa/R101EZxIJyZZDtjyajPUP3Zo7LfxXZpVgg8xXAE6xY3PGlJ

   -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the down votes on the question..

Comment: OpenSSL - it can be done using 'openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024' but is there a way to do it straight away in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate RSA key pair and encode private as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709441/generate-rsa-key-pair-and-encode-private-as-string)

Comment: i refrained from marking as duplicate because that answer doesn't convert to PEM format

Comment: SSH uses a different public key format, but the private key for OpenSSL and OpenSSH uses PKCS #1. An [answer I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19435226/3474)  performs decoding for PKCS #1 private keys. I don't have time right now to write the encoding, but maybe it would serve as a hint. The public key could use some of the same methods for big integer encoding.

Comment: @erickson: OpenSSH normally uses either PKCS1-PEM or in 6.5+ its own 'new' format which is PEM of a format that is internally XDR style, but Open**SSL** supports PKCS1, both variants of PKCS8, and (somewhat) PKCS12; the example in this Q is unencrypted PKCS8.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Sure, but the example in the comment is PKCS #1. So we can't say what he needs for sure.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You say 'the' format supported by OpenSSL, but OpenSSL supports multiple formats for (RSA and other) private keys, over a dozen depending how you count.

The particular formats you show, perhaps coincidentally, are the PEM forms of the two formats directly supported by *Java* crypto, PKCS8-unencrypted for private and 'X.509' (really SubjectPublicKeyInfo aka SPKI) for public, and thus can be created simply:

```
//nopackage
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class SO43459993SimpleRSAPEM {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048); KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        System.out.println ("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----");
        System.out.println (Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString( kp.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
        System.out.println ("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");
        System.out.println ("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----");
        System.out.println (Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString( kp.getPublic().getEncoded()));
        System.out.println ("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");

    }
}
```

Example output:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAomk/8wcY0umQYgm1AYlBYq5t/8aPgPC2
N8gbH37uv+pjtGcK1zbax5qUBHZXef1zPpPLyjhPik33lMIpCji5x3rs1eaqzuP1mTw8s4IFxqha
4CN/1k/AKk3AJnNtQhvdlsfqJlWhcpeY+f0oemmqWJekxu6l+DV8xJZ+ymu9AM9/ZyraoqHuywOQ
EY3MjgUT11YNjqvzvl0sMv3qRRyLPN7nLMBdY/+Db+Lu47giEOPrEBcgVMIdnaHIB/fi7DENfGtj
d5ITW4cQ/U5HobkhlPvyh3dDphF1R8encRL71UxvjGLrqgW1MXZ0XoIE3V+WyVF7c3/kTPusrqmr
izZSQwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```